# How can you get one file out of a another branch of a Git repository/

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using Git.  I have some code in one branch that I want to get.  Is there an easy way to get just the version of one file from a different branch or an easy way to make this other branch appear in another directory of my file system?

Just to be clear, I want to have this other version to examine, I don't want to completely replace the version I have with it.

I'm using SourceTree, but I'd be happy to accept command line based answers as well?

Comment: Have you figured out in SourceTree??

Answer (score 5):

I think (from the last entry in the documentation for git checkout), this will do what you're after (not sure about SourceTree though, sorry):

```
git checkout mybranch -- mypath/myfile
```

Source: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html

```
git checkout [-p|--patch] [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>…
```

> When `<paths>` or --patch are given, git checkout does not switch
>   branches. It updates the named paths in the working tree from the
>   index file or from a named `<tree-ish>` (most often a commit). In this
>   case, the -b and --track options are meaningless and giving either of
>   them results in an error. The `<tree-ish>` argument can be used to
>   specify a specific tree-ish (i.e. commit, tag or tree) to update the
>   index for the given paths before updating the working tree.

Answer (score 3):

For a quick look into a single file, [`git show`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html) is also an option:

```
git show otherbranch:./path/to/bar.foo
```

This output contents of bar.foo to stdout — which you can pipe to an editor if necessary:

```
git show otherbranch:./path/to/bar.foo | vim -
```